# Moving objects between lists AutoMapper and EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have started using [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) extension, and just want to say its excellent, thank you!

Now i have an issue, where an object can be moved from 1 collection, into another collection, and when i do this, i get an exception

> InvalidOperationException: Multiplicity constraint violated

I am guessing this is because the object isnt being found in the original collection, and this extension is adding the object to the new collection, even though i want it too be moved, then upon saving, EF throws the exception, because i have 2 objects with the same key against my context.

But how can i get this to work?

So if i have the following object structure

```
MyRoot
   | Collection
            | MyChild
                    | Collection
                            | MyObject (1)
            | MyChild
                    | Collection
                            | MyObject (2)
```

How can i move `MyObject (1)` into the same collection as `MyObject (2)`??

These are all basic objects, and here is some simple code

```
public class MyRoot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyChild> MyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RootId { get; set; }

    public MyRoot Root { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public MyChild Child { get; set; }
}
```

Each of these objects have a DTO, for the sake of this example, lets just say the objects are exactly the same, with extension DTO on the end (this is not the case in real application)

In my application, i then have an automapper profile, like so

```
internal class MyProfile: Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<MyRoot, MyRootDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();

        this.CreateMap<MyChild, MyChildDTO>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .EqualityComparison((s, d) => s.Id == d.Id);

        this.CreateMap<MyObject, MyObjectDTO>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .EqualityComparison((s, d) => s.Id == d.Id);
    }
}
```

On my web api controller method, i have this, which is very simple

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromBody] MyRootDTO model)
{
    // get the object and all children, using EF6
    var entity = await _service.GetAsync(model.Id);

    // map
    _mapper.Map(model, entity);

    // pass object now updated with DTO changes to save
    await _service.UpdateAsync(entity);

    // return
    return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<MyRootDTO>(entity));
}
```

If someone could please help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, i didnt change EF keys, but implemented a method in my AutoMapper profile.  I looped through the object to see if the child was in a different list, and if so, moved the object into that new list.  This way automapper will be able to match the object based on ID still.

I added the below code into the `.BeforeMap` method

Not that my base level object is called `Root` in this example, so parameter `s` is type `RootModel` (from my web api) and parameter `d` is type `Root` (from EF). Both `RootModel` and `Root` have a collection called `Sections`

```
.BeforeMap((s, d) =>
{
    // we are going to check if any child has been moved from 1 parent to another, and
    // if so, move the child before the mapping takes place, this way AutoMapper.Collections will not
    // mark the object as orphaned in the first place!
    foreach (var srcParent in s.Sections)
    {
        // only loop through old measures, so ID will not be zero
        foreach (var srcChild in srcParent.Children.Where(e => e.Id != 0))
        {
            // check if the srcChild is in the same dest parent?
            var destChild = d.Sections.SelectMany(e => e.Children).Where(e => e.Id == srcChild.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            // make sure destination measure exists
            if (destChild != null)
            {
                // does the destination child section id match the source section id? If not, child has been moved
                if (destChild.ParentId != srcParent.Id)
                {
                    // now we need to move the child into the new parent, so lets find the destination
                    // parent that the child should be moved into
                    var oldParent = destChild.Parent;
                    var newParent = d.Sections.Where(e => e.Id == srcParent.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                    // remove child from children collection on oldSection and add to newSection
                    oldParent.Children.Remove(destChild);

                    // if newParent is NULL, it is because this is a NEW section, so we need to add this new section
                    // NOTE: Root is my based level object, so your will be different
                    if (newParent == null)
                    {
                        newParent = new Parent();
                        d.Sections.Add(newParent);
                        newParent.Root = d;
                        newParent.RootId = d.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // change references on the child
                        destChild.Parent = newParent;
                        destChild.ParentId = newParent.Id;
                    }

                    newParent.Children.Add(destChild);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with AutoMapper here, it's an Entity Framework problem.  If you remove something from a child collection in EF, it doesn't automatically get deleted unless you either call a .Delete on it, or the key for the object is a composite key including the parent.

I would suggest making a composite key, such as the following:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public MyChild Child { get; set; }
}
```

The `[DatabaseGenerated]` option keeps the `Id` column as an Identity - EF's default with a composite key is for no automatic identity.

You can do the same thing on your `MyChild` entity.

Comment: if i do that, EF tries to generate the fields against the child table as well?  Is it supposed to do that?  Since this is a simple example, its ok, but my actual system references fields everywhere and lots of foreign key fields are trying to be added.....

Comment: It does mean you need additional key fields to make your relationships work with multi-level, but it's up to you whether you want this functionality.  Without this, you'll need to specifically reference the EF stuff in order to move an entity.

Comment: When you say "specifically reference the EF stuff in order to move an entity", what do you mean?

Comment: [This](http://phdesign.com.au/programming/delete-dependent-entities-when-removed-from-ef-collection/) should explain more.  Although you are not trying to delete, it's the same explanation.